# Can not run cucumber-jest features in my project

Tags: ts-jest, cucumberjs, babel-jest

I am having trouble to run a feature file in my project with `jest-cucumber`. Since I am using already jest in my project I assume that the issue is some wrong configuration or version conflict.

I am trying to run the [basic example](https://github.com/bencompton/jest-cucumber/blob/master/examples/typescript/specs/features/basic-scenarios.feature) from the `cucumber-jest` github page with via cli but I get the following error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

      at ScriptTransformer._getTransformer (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:360:13)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:427:28)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)
```

This is the configuration/packages I am using:
`jest.config`:

```
module.exports = {
  testRegex: 'specs/.*\\.(test|spec|steps)\\.[jt]s$',
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel'
}
```

npm packages which might be of relevance:

```
"jest-cucumber": "^3.0.1",
"@cucumber/gherkin": "^17.0.0",
"@types/jest": "27.0.2",
"babel-jest": "27.4.2",
"jest": "27.0.4",
"jest-junit": "12.2.0",
"ts-jest": "27.0.3",
"ts-loader": "9.2.6",
"typescript": "4.9.5",
```

If I remove the `preset` from my `jest.config` I receive the following error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
```

I tried to meddle with different versions of the packages but without any result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `jest-cucumber` to the root `package.json`